# Is there any very bare minimal ftp server for ubuntu that wouldn't conflict with other installed servers?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I have installed proftpd with mod-sql modules; i need to have a ftp server that would run on another port (and use a separate authentication scheme)

Whenever i try to install vsftpd or pureftpd it simply removes proftpd and dependencies; i'm guessing it's to prevent having conflicts ...

Is there any 'very small' ftp server; like run from command line that I could use ?

I've searched all around but cannot find ...

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot use ProFTPd's virtual hosts feature? That works just like in Apache; you can make ProFTPd listen to additional ports/IP addresses and give that virtual host completely different configuration than for the others.

Proftpd.org has [an example configuration file](http://proftpd.org/docs/configs/virtual.conf) illustrating this.

Comment: Well no; my goal is to have two different ftp servers running on two different ports; you didn't understand my point.

Comment: What did I miss? Virtual hosts can be configured to behave like completely different servers with separate authentication schema (or even anonymous access) and so on.

Comment: Ok maybe not clear; I'm using the mod_sql for auth; thus binding to only 1 table for users; i don't think i can actually assign more than 1 authentication sheme sepecially in virtual hosts; or i'm totally dumb

Comment: Yes you can. Each and every ProFTPd mod_sql parameter is applicable in <VirtualHost> context, so you can use even a different database server for different virtual hosts, if you so will. See here: proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sql.html

Comment: oh ok; didn't knew that. i'll give a try. Thanks !